# How to fix this spotify error?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, spotify

I have Xubuntu 64 bit 14.04, latest version of spotify and it seems to be working fine, but I see this error.

[image]

I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But that do no fix it, I keep seeing

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: @jooon I flagged it, the mods will do what the mods do. Anyhow wouldn't your solution mean that I wouldn't be able to update to a newer version?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I updated the answer to remind people to add the repository again when everything is working.

Comment: @jooon would you please leave a comment to this question (if you still remember :p) just to notify me when the issue is fixed so I can add the repo again? and one more thing, I think it's better if you copy your answer to here, because after I accept your answer, we can mark the other question as duplicate to this one. As for now, we can't mark this question as duplicate to the other one because the other guy hasn't accepted your answer